# настроить проект autoconf или cmake

Tags: linux, c, windows, cmake, autoconf

У меня проблема. Использую autoconf. Я настраиваю сборку программы. Вот что я добавил.

Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = cymix
cymix_SOURCES = cymix.c errors.c my_ip.c net.c parse-conf.c parse-my-rules.c parse-option.c queue.c
```

делаю automake и он пишет

```
configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
```

Вот что у меня в configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([cymix], [0.1], [naidv88@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS(config.h)

AC_CHECK_HEADER([pcap/pcap.h],
        [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_PCAP_H], 1, [Define to 1 if you have <pcap/pcap.h>.])],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([sorry, can't do anything for you])])

AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([SYSCONFDIR], ["$sysconfdir"], [cymix.conf])

AC_OUTPUT
```

Но я не уверен что правильно делаю. Мне надо чтобы файл cymix.conf попал в каталог конфигурации взависимости от того как будет сконфигурирован билд, в /usr/ или в /usr/local. Также мне надо записать несколько переменных, которые будут содержать путь к каталогу. Например к файлу /usr/local/etc/cymix.conf.
Вы уж помогите.

Comment: *configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.* — `$ aclocal` забыли выполнить?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin наверное забыл. Но я пока не буду пробывать эти настройки, пока по всем вопросам мне не помогут, а пока я сделал configure смотря на configure ffmpeg, у них самописный. Я сделал такой, который генерит makefile, смотрит prefix и добавляет глобальные #define для программы. Этого пока хватает.

Comment: Поскольку у Вас фигурирует *cmake* в вопросе, то вставлюсь. В своё время пытался разобраться с "автотулз", пришёл в ужас и перешёл на *cmake*. Не пожалел. Рекомендую очень хорошую книжку, в которой Вы наверняка найдёте ответы на все Ваши вопросы: Д.В. Дубров "СИСТЕМА ПОСТРОЕНИЯ ПРОЕКТОВ CMAKE". В одну строчку решаются задачи, которые требуют десятков строк в автотулзах.

Comment: @Sergey о, спасибо.